# How can I "try out" Tensorflow functions in iPython and see the answers?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Sometimes I really just want to interactively experiment with things like `softmax()`, or `sigmoid()` just to get a sense of how they behave. I'm struggling to be able to see the answer. Maybe I need to rewrite everything in numpy, but I hope not.

Example:

```
v = tf.sigmoid(tf.convert_to_tensor([0.123, 0.345]))
```

Now I have `v`, but heck if I can figure out how to see the values inside it.  How can it be done?

Comment: What about `print(v)`? Since this question is tagged `tensorflow2.0` I assume that is the version you are using.

Comment: For me it just prints the name, shape and data type, not the values.

Comment: Are you sure you are using TF2.0? You can check via `print(tf.__version__)

Comment: ```v.numpy()``` ?

Comment: Yeah, version 2.0.0

Answer (score 1):

In case you are running Tensorflow 2.0 -

```
v = tf.sigmoid(tf.convert_to_tensor([0.123, 0.345]))
v.numpy()
```

The answer is -

```
array([0.5307113, 0.5854046], dtype=float32)
```

If you are running Tensorflow 1.0 -

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(v.eval())
```

It gives the following answer -

```
[0.5307113 0.5854046]
```

Comment: I'm running 2.0.0 and get "Tensor object has no attribute numpy"?  EDIT: I suspect it's related to eager execution.  I have it disabled because my stuff all broke when I went from 1.x.

Comment: @Mastiff - Then maybe the eval() function helps?